# How can I work around Read-only SQL users finding out an MSSQL app login without needing to take a production outage?

Tags: active-directory, sql-server

I've inherited a 3-tier production environment where some app servers are using a local SQL admin login to integrate to the database (terrible, I know).

Some honest developers recently disclosed to me that they found out the password for this login.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to restrict developers (or anyone already with with Read-only access to the MSSQL instance) without resetting the app-MSSQL integration login's password (which would entail an outage).

This would obviously be a temporary measure (needless to say an urgent one).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your infrastructure, you should be able to restrict login to particular machines. If you restrict network logins for that account apart from the application itself, you should be safe.